# jquery lightbox is not working

Tags: jquery, html, image, lightbox2

I am trying to set custom width and height on lightbox image popup but i am getting error `$(...).lightBox is not a function`

Jquery version: 1.12

lightbox version: 2.9

Following is my html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <link href="css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>  
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('a').lightBox({
                          maxHeight: 700, 
                          maxWidth: 700
                    });
                });
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a style="color: blue" href="images/sampleinvoice.jpg" data-lightbox="sampleinvoice" data-title="Sample Invoice">Sample Invoice</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: May be you need to initialize as `$(a[data-lightbox="simpleinvoice"])`. But I am not sure. May be try placing lightbox.min.js at the bottom of body tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After looking more into http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#options, i found that following is correct way to customize lightbox

```
                lightbox.option({
                    maxHeight: 1000, 
                      maxWidth: 1250
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you don't capitalize the "B" in `.lightBox`.